# Does xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" still have a function?

Tags: html

I saw this today in the -Tag of a project. I think this is deprecated.

```
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="" lang="de">
```

Comment: Depends on the DOCTYPE, HTML5 is [namespace ignorant](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Why_no_namespaces), XML isn't, XHTML neither.

Comment: The doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>". So this means its not necessary?

Comment: yep, completely useless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**xlink** namespace is not **depricated**. See [Xml Linking Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/) specification, but it is optional from **HTML5** to include the `xmlns` attribute to your **HTML** page. So if you use **HTML5+** you should have no use for that link.

[Link to w3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_html_xmlns.asp)

> Note: The xmlns attribute is required in XHTML, invalid in HTML 4.01,
> and optional in HTML5.
>
> Note: The HTML validator at http://w3.org does not complain when the
> xmlns attribute is missing in an XHTML document. This is because the
> namespace "xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" is default, and will be
> added to the  tag even if you do not include it.

Comment: Ok, but is it still used in todays basic webpages?

Comment: From Html 5 it is not needed anymore.

Comment: That "link to w3" is a link to w3schools 

Answer (score 0):

XLink is used to create hyperlinks in XML documents. There is no browser support for XLink in XML documents.

Comment: SVG1.1 is one XML format where browsers do support part-of xlink.

Comment: Ok, but this is inside an SVG-Element. In an html-tag in the <!DOCTYPE html> it has no use?

Comment: I think so : ) @Peesen87